# Dictionary with same keys in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a json object using Dictionary in python. As far as I understand the key part needs to be unique but in my case the array has multiple items with the same key so looks like Dictionary will not work for me here. Trying to understand my options here? Finally I will be saving this json object into a json file on the server.

```
data = {}
data['key1'] = hostname

for line in pipe.stdout:
    parts = line.split() # split line into parts
    if len(parts) > 1:   # if at least 2 parts/columns
        data['package'] = { 'name': parts[0], 'installed': parts[1], 'available': parts[2]}

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Expected Json Output

```
{

 "key1": "xyz-abc-m001",
 "package": [
   { "name":"abc", "installed":"1:1", "available":"1:1.2." },
   { "name":"xyz", "installed":"2.02", "available":"2.02" },
   { "name":"zyc", "installed":"1.17.1", "available":"1.17.1" }

 ]

}
```

Comment: what do you want as an output? you could create a dictionary containing lists.

Comment: Those are multiple dictionaries with unique keys per dict.

Comment: I don't think i can use as a list because my array is in the form of key: value pair right ? the output i expect is the json i mentioned in my question.

Comment: `"package"` is a `list` of type `dict`. Each element in `package` is its own `dict`, so there are no duplicate keys.

Comment: @MarshOps Try *deserializing* your expected JSON output, and then look at what kind of structure Python made from that. That’s what you should try to replicate using your Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {}
data['key1'] = hostname
data['package'] = []

for line in pipe.stdout:
    parts = line.split() # split line into parts
    if len(parts) > 1:   # if at least 2 parts/columns
        data['package'].append({ 'name': parts[0], 'installed': parts[1], 'available': parts[2]})
```